# how does the function return type works as shown below?

Tags: c

I am wondering if anyone can help explain the function return type work in a detailed way.

For example, if the return type is int, how does it saved? in 64 bits CPU, assuming register is 64 bits, then how does it save in one register? the lower 8 bits?

Then how about double double which will be 128 bits be saved? in two registers?

Then how the other parts of the code know where the return value is?

THank you for your help,

Brian

Comment: google the terms "ABI"  and "calling convention"

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question, as the answer reveals a lot about what's going on under the hood even though it mostly doesn't impact how you write your software.

First: the answer depends a **lot** on the CPU you're using, as each architecture has its own conventions for dealing with registers and return values and the like. As noted in a comment above, "ABI" is Application Binary Interface defines a set of conventions that everybody has to agree on.

The ABI is how you drill down on your particular platform, and this post is *at best* a drive by.

For simple returns - an integer, for instance - almost all CPUs have an "obvious" register to use for this, and on the Intel x86 platform it's `eax`, and for x64 it's `rax`.

This is essentially the "A" register shared (at least notionally) by many processors, and a function/subroutine stores the return value here to make it available to the caller.

In these cases, whatever the caller finds in this "A" register is considered the return, but it has no way of knowing whether the subroutine intentionally put a value here for return, or if it's just some random leftover from a calculation.

This has a curious side effect that a function that does not intentionally return a value nevertheless "returns" whatever happens to be in the `eax` register when it returns. Sometimes this is the result of a calculation, sometimes it's the return value from a sub-function called just before return.

```
int myfunc()
{
   .. do some stuff
   int x = 4 * other_function();
   // note no "return"
}
```

It might be that the calculated `x` is "returned" just because it happened to have landed in the A register, but don't count on it: it's essentially a bug. It could also be some other value. A good compiler will warn you for dodgy business like this: there are questions on SO all the time about these mystery returns.

Of course, it's not always that simple: you can't fit a 128-bit value into a 64-bit register, so functions that return a `double` (or a `long long`) have to take other provisions.

For integral values, many architectures agree on using two registers together, and for floating point values, there could be a separate set of floating point registers used that the caller agrees to consult.

It's *vital* that the caller and callee agree on where these are to go.

A special case is returning a large item, such as a structure. This is not a great idea and most do not recommend it (though legal), and it should be obvious that returning a (say) 488 byte structure will not fit in registers on most architectures.

The trick is that the caller allocates space for the full return value and then passes the address of that return area in a hidden argument to the function (sometimes in the "A" register). The callee knows to copy the computed structure to the memory pointed to by that hidden pointer.

Ref: [How do C compilers implement functions that return large structures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155730/how-do-c-compilers-implement-functions-that-return-large-structures)

As mentioned, this is just a drive by, and you really have to study the architecture of the processor you're working with, but the most important fact here: these are *conventions*, which means that they are just something that everybody agrees on rather than being some inherent "right" answer.

Comment: Register `A` is commonly called the *accumulator* because it accumulates the result of operations. On some architectures its mnemonical name is `ACC`, consequentially. Some other like PIC call it `W` for *working register*.

Comment: thank you! what is eax, and  rax? how about for arm architecture? Thank you, Brian